# Add new column to df based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to below:

```
A        B       C
GCSE     yes     GQ
GCSE     no      GQ
NVQ      no      VQ
NVQ      yes     VQ
```

I need to add a fourth column based on the values of columns B and C. There are four possible outcomes, EPS, HCI, CAMS, DIGI. They need to be as follows:

```
B    C     D
yes  GQ    HCI
no   GQ    EPS
yes  VQ    DIGI
no   VQ    CAMS
```

The dataframe is about 37,000 rows...

Can anyone advise the simplest way to do this? I am struggling to find an answer that does not involve adding, subtracting, multiplying or dividing values from two columns to fill the new column.

Thanks

Comment: What is expected output if last `VQ` is `AQ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and use the [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method - this works because columns B and C are strings :

```
mapping = {"yes,GQ": "HCI", "no,GQ": "EPS", "yes,VQ": "DIGI", "no,VQ": "CAMS"}

df = df.assign(D=df.B.str.cat(df.C, sep=",").map(mapping))

df

       A    B   C   D
0   GCSE    yes GQ  HCI
1   GCSE    no  GQ  EPS
2   NVQ     no  VQ  CAMS
3   NVQ     yes VQ  DIGI
```

You could also use [numpy select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), which is similar to SQL's `case when`; I do think map suffices for this. Do test it though to verify the speed, since you have a lot of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with new DataFrame with all combinations in lists:

```
d = {'B': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no'], 
     'C': ['GQ', 'GQ', 'VQ', 'VQ'], 
     'D': ['HCI', 'EPS', 'DIGI', 'CAMS']}

df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(d), on=['B','C'], how='left')
print (df)
      A    B   C     D
0  GCSE  yes  GQ   HCI
1  GCSE   no  GQ   EPS
2   NVQ   no  VQ  CAMS
3   NVQ  yes  VQ  DIGI
```